# rails rubocop use && instead of and with render and return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, rubocop

I have been stuck on this issue for some time now, but keep skipping over it.  If I follow the cop guidelines here and change this to && my routes break. They are connected to my routes via:

```
  # Override Error Codes
  match '/404', to: 'error#four_oh_four', via: :all
  match '/422', to: 'error#four_twenty_two', via: :all
  match '/500', to: 'error#five_hundred', via: :all
```

Do you recommend disabling this cop for this issue or is there a better way to adjust this?

[image]

```
class ErrorController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :ensure_trailing_slash
  before_action :load_log_service

  def javascript_disabled
    @log_service.capture_message(view_context.time_stamp('javascript_disabled'), 'error_scope')
    render_error_application_requirements t('system_requirements.minimum_settings.javascript_disabled')
  end

  def system_requirements
    @log_service.capture_message(view_context.time_stamp('system_requirements'), 'error_scope')
    render_error_application_requirements t('system_requirements.minimum_settings.system_requirements')
  end

  def browser_upgrade_required
    @log_service.capture_message(view_context.time_stamp('browser_upgrade_required'), 'error_scope')
    render_error_application_requirements t('system_requirements.minimum_settings.browser_upgrade_required')
  end

  def four_oh_four
    @log_service.capture_message(view_context.time_stamp('four_oh_four'), 'error_code')
    render_error_status_code('Page Not Found', '404', t('system_requirements.response_code.four_oh_four'))
  end

  # four_twenty_two, five_hundred :: no custom report needed, they are picked up by the sentry gem
  def four_twenty_two
    render_error_status_code('Application Error', '422', t('system_requirements.response_code.four_twenty_two'))
  end

  def five_hundred
    render_error_status_code('Application Error', '500', t('system_requirements.response_code.five_hundred'))
  end

  private

  def render_error_application_requirements(title)
    @title = title
    render 'errors/application_requirements', layout: 'errors/application_requirements' and return
  end

  def render_error_status_code(title, error_code, error_msg)
    @title = title
    @error_code = error_code
    @error_msg = error_msg
    render 'errors/status_code', layout: 'errors/status_code', status: @error_code and return
  end

  def load_log_service
    @log_service = LogService.new
  end
end
```

Comment: Seems like you dont need `and return`  expression in this case

Comment: @ProgNoob that is odd, if I leave them out in the past it blew up my custom error pages.  If you could post this as an answer and helpful explanation for others about `and return` and how / when to use it I'm down to give your answer credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a comment under your Post, indeed you don't need to `return` here.

However if you still want to use `return` and have it following RuboCop style, try wrapping render params with brackets.

`render('errors/status_code', layout: 'errors/status_code', status: @error_code) && return`

Answer (score 4):

I think your lack of parens around the arguments to your `render` calls here is confusing you. `&&` has higher precedence than `and` and the difference is changing how Ruby identifies the arguments to `render`.

Guessing is no fun though, let's find out for sure. MRI Ruby includes [`Ripper`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) which allows us to inspect how an expression will be parsed.

```
require 'ripper'
require 'pp'
```

*and*

```
Ripper.sexp("render 'errors/application_requirements', layout: 'errors/application_requirements' and return")
```

---

```
[:program,
 [[:binary,
   [:command,
    [:@ident, "render", [1, 0]],
    [:args_add_block,
     [[:string_literal,
       [:string_content, [:@tstring_content, "errors/status_code", [1, 8]]]],
      [:bare_assoc_hash,
       [[:assoc_new,
         [:@label, "layout:", [1, 29]],
         [:string_literal,
          [:string_content,
           [:@tstring_content, "errors/status_code", [1, 38]]]]],
        [:assoc_new,
         [:@label, "status:", [1, 59]],
         [:var_ref, [:@ivar, "@error_code", [1, 67]]]]]]],
     false]],
   :and,
   [:return0]]]]
```

---

*&&*

```
Ripper.sexp("render 'errors/application_requirements', layout: 'errors/application_requirements' && return")
```

---

```
[:program,
 [[:command,
   [:@ident, "render", [1, 0]],
   [:args_add_block,
    [[:string_literal,
      [:string_content, [:@tstring_content, "errors/status_code", [1, 8]]]],
     [:bare_assoc_hash,
      [[:assoc_new,
        [:@label, "layout:", [1, 29]],
        [:string_literal,
         [:string_content,
          [:@tstring_content, "errors/status_code", [1, 38]]]]],
       [:assoc_new,
        [:@label, "status:", [1, 59]],
        [:binary,
         [:var_ref, [:@ivar, "@error_code", [1, 67]]],
         :"&&",
         [:return0]]]]]],
    false]]]]
```

The output from Ripper isn't the easiest thing to read but if we pay close attention to the indentation of those function call we can see that the `and` case is calling `render(... '..._requirements') and return` while the `&&` case is calling `render(... '..._requirements' && return)`. Those two expressions are going to have very different behaviors.

Comment: That's one nice explanation! Thank you for sharing this awesome Ripper, didn't know Ruby has something awesome like this built-in, prbly many people as well, quite useful.